# Em que linguagem/framework/banco são feitos os sites Stack Exchange?

Tags: debate, stackexchange

Em que linguagens de programação, frameworks, bancos de dados, bibliotecas e metodologias foram feitos os sites da rede?

Pergunto tanto do back-end como do front-end.

Comment: Está pergunta pertence ao meta. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange-network

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A linguagem é C#, usando ASP.NET MVC em cima de um pequeno framework ORM chamado Dapper:

> https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net

Há também [ElasticSearch.net](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/_elasticsearch_net.html) e [Redis](https://msopentech.com/opentech-projects/redis/) como *caches*.

Isto porque [o Jeff Atwood falou num post do blog dele](http://blog.codinghorror.com/why-ruby/) que o Stack Overflow foi escrito usando C# e .NET, e que a próxima plataforma em que ele estava trabalhando, o Discourse, seria feita em Ruby.

Tem uma [lista de projetos que o Stack Overflow usa e que estão detalhados aqui](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/stack-exchange-open-source-projects/). A Roberta, programadora do Stack Overflow, [montou esta apresentação em que tudo isso é explicado](http://docplayer.com.br/3642486-A-arquitetura-do-stack-overflow.html).

O Data Explorer usa SQL Server:

> https://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/

Comment: Sim, que eu saiba todos usam SQL Server. Usam também o Redis pra algumas coisas (notificações acho que é uma delas).

Comment: "CACHE ALL THE THINGS" :D

Answer (score 5):

Os sites da rede Stack Exchange são desenvolvidos em ASP.NET MVC com C# e utilizam banco de dados SQL Server e ORM Dapper. Utiliza uma arquitetura monolítica.

Não é utilizado conceitos como TDD ou DDD. Todo esforço colocado é para maximização da performance do site, para que suporte milhões de usuários sem que seja necessário adquirir muito hardware.

A Roberta Arcoverde, desenvolvedora da rede Stack Exchange, fez uma [palestra](https://www.infoq.com/br/presentations/a-arquitetura-peculiar-do-stack-overflow) que foi gravada, ela explica bem sobre o assunto. Vale muito a pena assistir a palestra que tem duração de 41 minutos.

Resumo(extraído do site)

> Na Stack Exchange, mantemos uma rede de sites que recebe 20 milhões de visitantes únicos por mês usando apenas 9 servidores web. A arquitetura é monolítica, usando data center próprio, metade do time trabalha remotamente, não escrevemos testes automatizados e frequentemente reinventamos rodas. Na palestra explico como funciona a arquitetura e as motivações por trás de tantas escolhas controversas.

Espero que o [link](https://www.infoq.com/br/presentations/a-arquitetura-peculiar-do-stack-overflow) da palestra não seja quebrado num futuro breve