# Por que não temos um compilador PHP?

Tags: novo-recurso

Tenho observado, aliás todos provavelmente, que a *tag* [php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) talvez, eu digo talvez, tenha o maior número de perguntas da comunidade, pelo menos SOpt.

As vezes cansa de ficar indo lá no IDEONE ou Codpad, etc, e tal. Então estive pensando, por que? Considerando toda grandiosidade desta comunidade, ainda não temos um compilador PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Imagine dedicar um (ou mais) servidor(res) para executar coisas como:

- PHP (com versões entre 5.1 até 7.1)
- .NET (2.0 até 4.6 e .NET Core)
- Java (6 até 8)
- Python 2 e 3
- C++ e C (esse parece complicado, afinal as coisas variam de compilador para compilador)
- *(Dentre outras)*

Porque se for para executar PHP, também terá que executar outras linguagens populares do mercado, creio eu.

Teria que ter um (ou mais) servidor(res) dedicados apenas para isto e acredito que o numero de usuários que usam o *ideone* é relativamente baixo se comparado a perguntas geradas no SOen, SOpt, SOes, SOja

Agora imagine disponibilizar uma estação para fazer este trabalho, com múltiplos acessos, edições, testes, variantes, provavelmente seria um servidor bem instável, já que muitas situações nem poderia ter cache devido as modificações.

O outro problema é que teria que implementar um *sandbox* (isto seria necessário para evitar problemas de segurança) e para cada linguagem teria que ter um lógica de sandbox o que exigiria também contratar um profissional para cada área, se não fizer isso poderá expor o servidor ou até mesmo derrubar ele.

Fora que com tudo isso, tomaria um grande tempo, energia, investimento e para não ter nenhum retorno de verdade para a empresa (creio eu).

Talvez você não conheça a infraestrutura dos sites da *Stack Overflow*, mas por incrível que pareça eles conseguem rodar tudo (creio eu que se refere a todos sites e chat) com apenas 9 servidores (se entendi bem), tem cache de tudo. Agora imagine o quanto de servidores que eles teriam que ter para manter uma boa performance para executar múltiplas linguagens a cada edição/correção (já que a resposta do script poderia ter um cache), seria um investimento alto (creio eu).

> Um pouco sobre as tecnologias usadas atualmente: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1451/3635

### Conclusão

Não deixa de ser uma boa ideia, mas as motivações para que isso seja inviável provavelmente são:

- Performance
- Custo
- Nem sempre é necessário executar algo
- Muitos códigos não são executáveis, pois as pessoas as vezes não sabem como transmitir o seu problema e usam o StackSnippet sem necessidade

Mas de fato quem pode apenas responder conclusivamente é alguém da *staff* (talvez o @Gabe)

Answer (score 8):

Todo mundo já respondeu... O benefício não justifica o custo.

Essa necessidade já é muito bem suprida pelos serviços que você citou, e criar um próprio dá um trabalho desgraçado. Pra resolver um problema já solucionado. É um pouco diferente do nosso Code Snippet, porque ele deu muito menos trabalho, requer muito menos manutenção e tinha potencial de afetar um número gigantesco de perguntas ([javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) sendo a primeira ou segunda maior tag em todos os SOs).

Fazer algo similar para linguagens desktop dependeria de muito mais trabalho e manutenção do que podemos dispendiar.

Answer (score 6):

Por que temos o browser para executar JS, HTML e CSS. O máximo que o site faz é pegar o código e disponibiliza-lo de modo que sua execução não comprometa "muito" o funcionamento do site. Já PHP é um pouco complicado. Pois vai ser necessário disponibilizar um servidor para ficar executando os códigos, ou implementar um interpretador em JS, que simule a execução do PHP, porem, implementar e manter isso(a cada atualização do PHP) é inviável, na minha opinião.