# Não seria interessante termos um formatador de SQL?

Tags: novo-recurso

Vejo muitos códigos SQL na rede difíceis de entender e mal formatados.

Eu por exemplo sempre uso o [SQLFORMAT](https://sqlformat.org/) para formatar meu `SQL` e inserir nas perguntas e ou respostas.

Não seria interesse uma opção para formatar nosso código `SQL`?

Comment: Seria interessante ter algo assim para todas linguagens. Todavia os problema para implementar algo assim dentro da comunidade seriam: UX destas ferramentas, tempo para desenvolver e testar. Relacionados: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5642/3635 e https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5756/3635

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento mas creio eu que o `SQL` é o mais comum que usamos depois do `JS`. Bacana, obrigado pelos esclarecimentos.

Comment: IMHO, formatação é gosto, e dependendo da resposta (ou mesmo pergunta), podemos querer destacar determinado trecho importante e outros não. Como ferramenta auxiliar (e opcional) poderia até ser de alguma utilidade, mas creio que está longe de ser prioridade no site. Eu acredito que seria mais o caso de uma ferramenta auxiliar (como uma extensão de _browser_, quem sabe). O @GuilhermeNascimento tem uma extensão interessante para usar na rede, quem sabe um dia ela ganhe um plugin para ferramentas externas como embelezadores de código, configuráveis pelo usuário  :)