# Como rodar Angular2+ (TypeScript) no Stack-Snippet do site principal?

Tags: suporte, stack-snippets

To tentando criar uma pergunta sobre um problema que tenho em projeto com Angular 8, e gostaria que fosse possível criar uma visualização que seja mais fiel ao que estou desenvolvendo, e não apenas uma versão do html simplificada sem o CSS dos componentes do material design.

Tentei usar o campo pra inserir `Trecho de JavaScript/HTMl/CSS` (stack-snippet) mas o resultado é o mesmo...

meu código:

```
 <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Número do item" formControlName="nItem" maxlength="15" id="nItem" required>
    <button mat-button matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear" (click)="value=''">
        <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <mat-hint>Número sequencial do item no arquivo</mat-hint>
    <mat-error *ngFor="let validation of message.nItem">
        <mat-error class="error-message" *ngIf="formproductpriceadd.get('nItem').hasError(validation.type) && (formproductpriceadd.get('nItem').dirty || formproductpriceadd.get('nItem').touched)">
            {{validation.message}}
        </mat-error>
    </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Até dá, mas não é simples, o que vai contra o que você precisa, na verdade é bem complexo, dá pra fazer usando https://unpkg.com, mas pra cada pergunta vai ter que copiar muitas coisas, de pronto imediato talvez o melhor mesmo seja usar de terceiros: https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: Relacionados: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5641/3635 e https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5756/3635 (sei que a pergunta é sobre front-end, mas ainda sim dependeria de aplicar uma espécie de "compilador" pra typescript, o que mesmo sendo mais fácil ainda sim necessitaria de algo proprio e isolado, talvez no futuro exista, mas entra na mesma linha de problema e que existem soluções de terceiros)