# O que quer dizer esta bola no menu "filas de análise"?

Tags: suporte, filas-de-análise, interface-usuário

Deparei-me com uma bola nas edições sugeridas o que quer ela dizer quando esta nessa cor:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Após ter clicado não apareceu nenhuma analise necessária, foi isso que me causou confusão e duvidas.

**EDIT1:** 03-10-2017

Hoje deparei-me com o seguinte, cliquei no ícone de "filas de análise" e mostrou que tinha análises a serem feitas nas "edições sugeridas", tal e qual como mostra na imagem acima. Cliquei e fiz as análises eram para ai umas 3 por isso penso estar tudo correto, tanto o aparecimento da bola como a sua cor.

Após as análises feitas voltei para a página "analisar" e por mais que fizesse `F5` continua a aparecer a bola vermelha, deixo um print:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Estive a pensar e lembrei-me do seguinte: para as edições sugeridas serem aceites devem ser analisadas por vários utilizadores, não basta um para a edição ser aprovada. Então será que existem edições por analisar mas no entanto já não estão disponíveis para mim por eu já ter analisado? Mas algum tipo de erro está a mostrar também para mim...

Espero ter conseguido explicar-me.

Comment: Para adicionar ao que já foi dito nas respostas abaixo: como o Shog explica [no SO inglês](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/355234/1328704), fizemos testes antes de decidir manter estes indicadores sem os números, tendo chegado à conclusão de que assim não só há mais cliques para as filas de análise, mas também é mais fácil direccionar os utilizadores para as filas que precisam de mais atenção imediata. Para finalizar, o número continua a ser visível se clicares em "[Todas as filas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review)."

Comment: @JNat obrigado pela informação adicional

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A ***intensidade*** da cor nas esferas define a quantidade, por exemplo no SOen:

> [image: cores]

Ou seja, vermelho é que tem muitas coisas, cinza tem alguns (ou um item apenas) e sem o circulo (ou "transparente") é que não tem nada.

Eu pessoalmente preferia quando tínhamos os números, poderiam ter combinado o numero com a cor, ou pode ser alguma dificuldade em contabilizar com precisão devido ao **cache** então eles podem ter preferido não fornecer números para evitar confusões de nossa parte ou então pode ser apenas questão de UX (User Experience).

O cache que me refiro não é o cache controlado por HTTP e pelo navegador, mas sim um cache do lado do servidor, nesta postagem é explicado quais tecnologias a Stack Overflow usa em seus sites da rede:

> [Em que linguagem/framework/banco são feitos os sites Stack Exchange?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1450/3635)

E a [Roberta Arcoverde](https://stackoverflow.com/cv/rarcoverde) montou esta apresentação que explica o *ecossistema*:

> [A arquitetura do Stack Overflow](http://docplayer.com.br/3642486-A-arquitetura-do-stack-overflow.html) (se quer ir direto ao ponto vá na página **25** diretamente *CACHE ALL THE THINGS*)

Comment: Obrigado pelo esclarecimento, no então após ter carregado não aparecia nada a necessitar de analise, e normal que acontecer?

Comment: @Tmc carregado o que?

Comment: cliquei no icon das filas de análise, apareceu a imagem tal e qual como mostro na pergunta, cliquei então para ir para a fila de análise "edições sugeridoas" mas não aparecia nenhum, eu pensei como e normal de acontecer já alguém analisou. No entanto volto a repetir o processo e acontece o mesmo aparece a bola mas análises nem velas fiz 'F5' há página, e nada então foi quando fiz a pergunta por não estar a perceber o significado da cor. Apesar de ter percebido a cor, ficar com a ideia de haver ali alguma possiblidade então de BUG

Comment: @Tmc é por causa do cache e/ou limite diário de edições, pessoas com score mais alto pode atuar mais na fila, se ainda seu score não for alto você só pode fazer algumas analises por dia. ... não posso afirmar que este é o seu problema, mas se entrar nesta página: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review talvez tenha alguma mensagem falando que o "seu limite já foi atingido"

Comment: O meu problema nao creio que seja o limite porque segundo sei o limite é de 20 analises por dia e eu ainda so tinha 10 naquele momento entretanto acho que ja fiz mais uma nessa fila..

Comment: @Tmc acho que não tem o que analisar e se ainda indica algo, mesmo não tendo nada na fila, é um "problema" de cache back-end. Como citei na resposta, existe um problema de precisão, por isto trocaram os numeros por cores. Assim evita as pessoas fazerem confusão (apenas suposição minha)

Comment: existe a possibilidade de ser problemas na cache, mas neste momento será difícil de descobrir a origem, obrigado a mesma

Comment: @Tmc então, mas é provavel que seja sim, o site usa cache-backend em tudo, tem até uma postagem aqui no Meta que explica o ecossistema dos sites da rede StackExchange. Lá fala sobre esse cache (que não é no navegador).

Comment: Obrigado mais uma vez, infelizmente não tenho ainda muita experiência em web, a qual me podia ajudar a intender melhor estes paradigmas, no entanto vou procurar o que fala sobre cache-backend,

Comment: Li em algum lugar no metão que iam tirar os números porque estava sendo custoso trazê-los, sendo algo que causava lentidão nos servidores. Provavelmente essas bolinhas acabaram sendo a solução.

Comment: @VictorStafusa legal saber, se achar o link me manda ;)

Comment: Não era exatamente o comentário que vi, mas mostra que era mais ou menos isso: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356697/top-bar-review-needed-red-dot-showing-but-no-red-dot-in-review-queues#comment517930_356726

Comment: Achei: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/353903/540552

Comment: Acabo de ver uma bola vermelha em edições sugeridas e uma bola cinza em publicações de baixa qualidade. Ambas possuíam apenas uma publicação que eu pudesse analisar.

Comment: @Renan realmente eu devo ter entendido errado. Mas pode ser questão do cache-back-end que eu já citei. Pra vc tinha só uma, mas pode indicar que mesmo que vc já tenha votado em tudo, elas ainda não fecharam. De qualquer forma irei confirmar. O proprio link do Victor mostra a situação diferente: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/353903/1518921

Comment: Encontrei esse tópico aqui também: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/355234/2263584 Nele o Shog9 explica melhor.

Comment: @Renan o pessoal da SO é tão paranoicos quanto eu em questão de reduzir tempo, conexões e criar caches hehehe, claro que uso a palavra paranoico como elogio e não como critica, se a metade dos programadores Desktop, Mobile e Web tivessem o minimo de preocupação com isto, teriamos apps mais eficientes e que exigiriam menos dos computadores, mas a maioria só se preocupa em fazer funcionar :(

Comment: Eu entendo a preocupação com cache e etc. Agora, isso dificultou pra quem é daltônico. Penso em sugerir ícones com formas diferentes além das cores.

Comment: @Renan a sim, mas isso é outra questão, ae é melhorar o UI pra favorecer a usabilidade, ou seja eles podem fazer isso de várias maneiras, um não necessariamente é ligado ao outro problema, na verdade a uns meses atrás esse menu nem existia, vc tinha que clicar pra entrar na fila e não tinha o "popup"

Comment: Meh. Eu preferia quando haviam números. A interface atual não me provoca vontade de analisar. Ao menos a página de filas ainda mostra os contadores, então agora eu começo por ela.

Comment: @Renan concordo a numeração ficava melhor

Comment: @Tmc pois é... Mas pelo menos assim o impacto na performance do site é menor, só vai carregar a numeração para quem for na página da fila.

Comment: @Renan pois é, eu também prefiro os numeros, como citei em minha resposta, mas ae é outro problema com que é questão de decisão da SO sobre "o que é melhor" ou "o que eles acreditam ser melhor". O máximo que podemos fazer é esperar que alguma postagem no Metão solicitando os numeros novamente tenha efeito, apesar de acreditar que o motivo seja evitar as margens de desentendimento sobre a quantidade exata já que o cache-back-end não atualiza na hora. PS: recomendo que leia isto (se ainda não leu): https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1450/3635

Answer (score 4):

A vermelha significa que tem muitos itens para serem analisados nesta fila de análise. A cinza indica que tem poucos itens. As demais não tem itens para analisar.

Antes tinha o número de itens, mas ele era confuso e talvez gerasse carga no servidor, agora é só isto.

Comment: mas por norma costumava aparecer a cinza, e neste momento carrego mas não aparece nada para analisar, por isso estranhei

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6407/o-que-quer-dizer-esta-bola/6410#comment24767_6410

Comment: Isso é praticamente uma [condição de corrida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101), mas são por *bug*, é que o estado muda mesmo, ocorre o tempo todo na vida.

Comment: existe essa possiblidade, faz algum sentido... obrigado

Comment: Por que o número de itens era confuso?

Comment: @Renan Não refletia exatamente o que tinha para você analisar.

Comment: @Maniero é isso que eu não entendo. Quando eu via 'X' análises a se fazer, eu seguia o link e de fato haviam 'X' análises. O número só era diferente quando havia alguma daquelas pegadinhas de teste. Fora isso não lembro de em ocasião nenhuma ver mais ou menos publicações para analisar do que dizia o número.

Comment: @Renan comigo nunca foi assim.