# O botão de fila de análise mostra o ícone mesmo sem ter análises a serem feitas

Tags: bug

Toda vez que entro no StackOverflow o botão de fila de análise está com o ícone de um circulo vermelho, na maioria das vezes quando clico nele não aparece nada para ser analisado e ainda o ícone só desaparece se atualizar a página, isto não é um bug?

Acontece só comigo?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [O que quer dizer esta bola?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6407/3635) e [O que é esta sinalização?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6455/3635) (ps: mesmo as perguntas não parecendo sobre o mesmo assunto nos títulos as respostas explicam o tal "problema")

Comment: Duplicata mesmo, tinha procurado perguntas sobre fila de análise e não achei essa, obrigado.